# Can i send an extra object to a javascript event and use the objects properties in the event?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a simple html that has multiple div elements.

```
<body onload="start()">
    <div id="image1"></div>
    <div id="image2"></div>
</body>
```

onload event of the body triggers a javascript function called start() that creates two objects from a class called img. The class creates a canvas in the div that it points to (the first parameter) with a width and height stated in the second and third parameters.

```
function start(){
    let img1 = new img("image1",640,480);
    let img2 = new img("image2",320,240);
}
```

The following class creates the canvas and an array which it fills with random numbers between 0-255. It also adds a mousemove event to the object.

```
class img{
    constructor(p_divid, p_w, p_h){ 
        this.divid = p_divid; //DIV id
        this.w = p_w; //width of the div        
        this.h = p_h; //height of the div
        this.pixels = []; //pixel values
        for (let index = 0; index < this.w*this.h; index++) {
            this.pixels[index] = Math.floor(Math.random()*255); //a random value up to 255
        }
        this.div = document.getElementById(this.divid); //div element
        this.div.innerHTML = "<canvas id='canvas-"+this.divid+"' width='"+this.w+"' height='"+this.h+"' style='background-color:red;'></canvas>"; //this creates a canvas
        this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-"+this.divid); //canvas element
        this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mmove); //mouse move event           
    }
```

the mousemove event gets the coordinates of the mouse relative to the element and calculates the position of the element that it wants to reach in the object's pixels. I want to learn the best practice to reach the objects pixels array.

```
    mmove(e){
        var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        var x = e.clientX - rect.left; 
        var y = e.clientY - rect.top;  
        var position_in_array = (y * 640) + x;
//******************************************************************************
        //THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO GET THE VALUE OF THE PIXELS ARRAY AND 
        //WRITE IT ON THE CONSOLE. Something like:
        //let x = object.pixels[position_in_array];
//******************************************************************************
    }
```

the whole html file that you see above is :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
        <body onload="start()">
            <div id="image1"></div>
            <div id="image2"></div>
        </body>
    
        <script>
            function start(){
                let img1 = new img("image1",640,480);
                let img2 = new img("image2",320,240);
            }
    
            class img{
                constructor(p_divid, p_w, p_h){ 
                    this.divid = p_divid; //DIV id
                    this.w = p_w; //width of the div        
                    this.h = p_h; //height of the div
                    this.pixels = []; //pixel values
                    for (let index = 0; index < this.w*this.h; index++) {
                        this.pixels[index] = Math.floor(Math.random()*255); //a random value up to 255
                    }
                    console.log(this.pixels);
                    this.div = document.getElementById(this.divid); //div element
                    this.div.innerHTML = "<canvas id='canvas-"+this.divid+"' width='"+this.w+"' height='"+this.h+"' style='background-color:red;'></canvas>"; //this creates a canvas
                    this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-"+this.divid); //canvas element
                    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mmove); //mouse move event
                }
    
                mmove(e){
                    var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
                    var x = e.clientX - rect.left; 
                    var y = e.clientY - rect.top;  
                    var position_in_array = (y * 640) + x;
//******************************************************************************
        //THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO GET THE VALUE OF THE PIXELS ARRAY AND 
        //WRITE IT ON THE CONSOLE. Something like:
        //let x = object.pixels[position_in_array];
//******************************************************************************
                }
            }
        </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is `object.pixels`? Is it same as `this.pixels`?

Comment: yes, the pixels object is this.pixels and its a part of the img class.

Comment: You need to use `bind()` to change the calling context of `this` ..... `addEventListener("mousemove", this.mmove.bind(this));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used `bind` method to pass extra arguments like

```
this.mmove.bind(null,this.pixels);

mmove(pixels, e){
```

Here is an example code on how you can pass extra argument with bind

```js
document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener('click', a.bind(null,12));

function a(v,e){
  alert(e.target.textContent);
  alert(v);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to 'charlietfl' for pointing me to the right direction.

changing my addeventlistener line to :

```
                this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mmove.bind(this));
```

and the mmove function to

```
    mmove(e){
                    var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
                    var x = e.clientX - rect.left; 
                    var y = e.clientY - rect.top;  
                    var position_in_array = (y * 640) + x;
                    let value = this.pixels[position_in_array];
                    console.log(value);
    }
```

solved my problem.